# How can I find a minimum value from a vector of entities?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
class enemy{
    ....
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<enemy> > enemies1;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    enemies1.emplace_back(...);

for (int i = 0; i < enemies1.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << i <<"x: " << enemies1[i]->rect.getPosition().x << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
100
200
400
```

How could I get the minimum coordinate value from multiple enemies in the vector? I want to detect the nearest enemy from the player, eg the player's coordinate is 50 and enemies are at 100, 200, 400, as you see in the above example. I want to detect the nearest enemy in the vector.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

Answer (score 0):

You can use min_element from

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct enemy_t
{
    explicit enemy_t(const double d) :
        distance{ d }
    {
    }

    double distance;
};

int main()
{
    // create a vector of enemies using the constructor with one double
    std::vector<enemy_t> enemies{ 100.0,400.0,200.0,10.0 };

    // the last argument to min_element is a lambda function 
    // it helps you define by what condition you want to find your element.
    auto enemy = std::min_element(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](const enemy_t& lhs, const enemy_t& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.distance < rhs.distance;
    });

    std::cout << "The minimum distance found = " << enemy->distance << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong implementation. You would need to have the lambda capture the player's position, and then have the lambda return which of the 2 parameters is closer to that position. The result of `min_element()` will then be an iterator to the enemy that is closest to the player.

Comment: Yup totally right that

Comment: Thaanks for spend your time and answers...

Answer (score 0):

For finding out the minimum you can use :

```
auto result = std::min_element(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](auto a, auto b){return a->rect.getPosition()< b->rect.getPosition();});
std::cout<<"minimum is: "<<(**result).rect.getPosition()<<std::endl;
```

The above example will print out the position of the closest(minimum) `enemy` as you want. You just need to add the above two statements into your program.

To **confirm** that this works(compile and gives the expected result), below i have given an example whose output can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hDNeyWrncgXMJJTe).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
struct Rectangle
{
    int getPosition() const 
    {
        return position;
    }
    Rectangle(int p):position(p)
    {
        
    }
    int position = 0;
};
struct enemy 
{
    Rectangle rect;
    enemy(int p): rect{p}
    {
        
    }

};
int main()
{
    std::vector<enemy*> enemies;
    enemy e1(600),e2(200),e3(400),e4(300), e5(100);
    enemies.push_back(&e1);
    enemies.push_back(&e2);
    enemies.push_back(&e3);
    enemies.push_back(&e4);
    enemies.push_back(&e5);
    
    auto result = std::min_element(enemies.begin(), enemies.end(), [](auto a, auto b){return a->rect.getPosition()< b->rect.getPosition();});
    std::cout<<"minimum is: "<<(**result).rect.getPosition()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```